# Adding more than one class list into one class list

Tags: c#, list, addition

I have to join more than one lists into a list.This question seems like common but my problem is may be quite different.
because, I have 3 classes. I have created 3 lists based on those classes

```
List<QTM> lstQTM = new List<QTM>();
List<QTMMain> lstQTMmain = new List<QTMMain>();
List<QTMStats> lstQTMStats = new List<QTMStats>();
```

these classes only indicate attribute which is stored into that lists.
I have created another list

```
 List<QTMList> lstQTMlist = new List<QTMList>();
```

this QTMList also a class. this class have

```
public class QTMList{
        public List<QTM> QTM { get; set; }
        public List<QTMStats> QTMStats { get; set; }
        public List<QTMMain> QTMMain { get; set; }
}
```

Now I tried to add lstQTM,lstQTMmain and lstQTMStats into lstQTMlist list. so I used

```
qtmList = new QTMList();
qtmList.QTMMain(lstQTMmain);
qtmList.QTM(lstQTM);
qtmList.QTMStats(lstQTMStats);

lstQTMlist.Add(qtmList);
```

I got the errors are

> C# Non-invocable 'lstQTMlist.lstQTMmain ' member cannot be used like a
>   method

and so on.

Could you please anyone give me any hint to solve my issue?

Comment: Are all the lists the same length?

Comment: @TheGeneral No sir, Those lengths are different

Comment: Can you just assing it: `qtmList.QTMMain = lstQTMmain;` or do you have to *clone* it (de-reference it/create  duplicate values)? Or add the new values to an already existing collection?

Comment: @Jimi is correct, nothing I can add.

Comment: The message tells your everything you need to know... you are calling it like a method, but it's not a method... `qtmList.QTM(lstQTM);` this is not valid c# ... your other calls also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use for settings.

```
qtmList = new QTMList();
qtmList.QTMMain=lstQTMmain;
qtmList.QTM=lstQTM;
qtmList.QTMStats=lstQTMStats;
```

Comment: Could you please explain why your solution works for the OP to help clarify why theirs wasnt working; it would add value.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a property like a method, the message is quite clear.

```
qtmList = new QTMList();
```

You can't do this for example:
 `qtmList.QTMMain(lstQTMmain)`;

You can add `1stQtMain` to `QTMMain` like this:

```
qtmList.QTMMain.AddRange(lstQTMmain)
```

You use `AddRange` to add a list of objects to a list.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the way you are using fields of your `QTMList` class. You are using
them like they were methods, i.e. passing arguments inside brackets. That's how you call a method.
In order to assign value to a field or property of a class you simply use `=` operator.
Thus, you code could be simplified to:

```
qtmList = new QTMList();
qtmList.QTMMain = new List<QTMMain>();
qtmList.QTM = new List<QTM>();
qtmList.QTMStats = new List<QTMStats>();
```

or you could initialize lists on `QTMList` initialization:

```
public class QTMList{
    public List<QTM> QTM { get; set; } = new List<QTM>();
    public List<QTMStats> QTMStats { get; set; } = new List<QTMStats>();
    public List<QTMMain> QTMMain { get; set; } = new List<QTMMain>();
}
```

Comment: A little late to the ball game... but yes you are right *somewhat*, what about assigning those lists to something the user has?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
qtmList = new QTMList();
qtmList.QTMMain = new List<QTMStats>(lstQTMmain);
qtmList.QTM = new List<QTM>(lstQTM);
qtmList.QTMStats = new List<QTMMain>(lstQTMStats);
```

By doing this, the new lists (QTMMain, ...) contain a copy of the items of the assigned lists (lstQTMmain, ...). You can simplify you code by adding the following constructor to QTMList:

```
public QTMList(List<QTM> qtm, List<QTMStats> qtmstats, qtmmain)
{
    QTMMain = new List<QTMStats>(lstQTMmain);
    QTM = new List<QTM>(lstQTM);
    QTMStats = new List<QTMMain>(lstQTMStats);
}
```

If you don't want a copy of the list contents, you should assign the Lists to the properties.

```
qtmList = new QTMList();
qtmList.QTMMain = lstQTMmain;
qtmList.QTM = lstQTM;
qtmList.QTMStats = lstQTMStats;
```